# Is "Do you miss me?" an interrogative sentence semantically?

Tags: meaning

> Do you miss me?

- Could you please tell me if it is an interrogative sentence **semantically** or a declarative one?

The fuller text is:

> She sits down on the bed in the gloomy room and pulls her husband’s
>   cell out of her pocket and looks at it.   [...] Then she looks at the
>   texts. She starts from the top of the list, ignoring names of people
>   she knows, but then she sees a woman’s name she doesn’t recognize. She
>   clicks on it and opens the text [...]
>
> Idk. I have to go away this weekend with the nag.
>
> When will I see you again?
>
> [...] She fights tears and continues reading.
>
> **>  I miss you terribly!**
>
> **> Do you miss me?**

Comment: I don't quite follow who's saying what in that text-message conversation.  It's possible such a question in context could be a rhetorical question. Consider the kind of affectionate patter between lovers, or between parent and (typically young) child, where a question is asked, basically repeating what has just been said, only in question form.  *I'm tired and would like to go to bed. -- Oh, is my baby tired?*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So, do you mean it isn't a real question semantically?

Comment: The semantics are complicated.   The asker already knows the answer but is asking the question solicitously (or in mock-solicitude when sarcasm is involved).  My example could be paraphrased (on a semantic level) as "I'm sorry, I did not realize you were tired" and in that case it's a statement in question form.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I mean **declarative sentence** not **declarative question** that you've mentioned below as a answer's comment.

Comment: @Peace Ah! Somehow I had misinterpreted that. In that case, I have to agree with the answer given. Even if no answer is *required*, a rhetorical question is still asking a question. But it's also only an assumption (or one possibility) that this is rhetorical in the first place—it could easily be expressing doubt and asking for confirmation instead.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the sources I could find, this is an interrogative sentence; the auxiliary verb (do) precedes the subject of the sentence, and the sentence ends in a question mark. In addition, by the intuitive definition that interrogative sentences are those which ask questions, this is quite clearly interrogative.

sources: 
https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-an-interrogative-sentence-1691183
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative
https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/helping-verbs.html